# How to "LoadLibrary" in C?

Tags: c

I have this code in Python which I want to convert to C:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
import sys

ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary (ctypes.util.find_library ('some_lib1') or 'some_lib2')
```

How do I do the same thing in C?

Comment: Have you tried searching for e.g. `LoadLibrary`? Have you tried to make any code?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, how would that me understand what the relevant C code is?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Seriously, [just search already](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=c%20loadlibrary). Then read. As normal, [wikipedia contains the cliff notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) (which quite often, as in this case, turn up fairly high in searches).

Comment: If you did a search, and you're on a Windows system, you should pretty quickly have come around [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which should tell you all you need to know, and also have a link to an example.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm not on Windows.

Comment: Then search for e.g. "c load library <your platform>", it's not that hard.

Comment: And no, *do not* put Python in this. Nobody in Python cares. That is merely used as the example to convey the intent.

Comment: @nos, you're such a pill, instead of simply asking a question, you're showing off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows search MSDN for LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx.

In Linux do a `man dlopen` in your console or search online.